# Out of nowhere getting the "The expression is typed incorrectly or too complex" error on a union query that I frequently use on Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a union query that pulls together data from a couple other queries. These queries search for data based on the date that is entered on a form.

I have been using this query for the longest time, and even have backups of this from months ago, when I know it worked, but suddenly, this error pops up instead.

The Union Query

```
SELECT MnthlyFireExCnt.ProjectCriteria AS Project, MnthlyFireExCnt.CountOfFire_Extinguisher_Location_ID_ AS NumberOf, MnthlyFireExCnt.Type
FROM MnthlyFireExCnt

UNION ALL 

SELECT MnthlyFrstAdCnt.ProjectCriteria, MnthlyFrstAdCnt.CountOfForm_Record_Number, MnthlyFrstAdCnt.Type
FROM MnthlyFrstAdCnt

UNION ALL 

SELECT MnthlyIncCnt.ProjectCriteria, MnthlyIncCnt.CountOfDate_Time_Reported, MnthlyIncCnt.Occurrence
FROM MnthlyIncCnt

UNION ALL 

SELECT MnthlyJHACnt.ProjectCriteria, MnthlyJHACnt.CountOfDate, MnthlyJHACnt.Type
FROM MnthlyJHACnt

UNION ALL 

SELECT MnthlySiteObsvCnt.ProjectCriteria, MnthlySiteObsvCnt.CountOfTime, MnthlySiteObsvCnt.Type
FROM MnthlySiteObsvCnt

UNION ALL 

SELECT MnthlySSICnt.ProjectCriteria, MnthlySSICnt.CountOfDate, MnthlySSICnt.InspCriteria
FROM MnthlySSICnt

UNION ALL 

SELECT MnthlyToolTCnt.ProjectCriteria, MnthlyToolTCnt.CountOfDate_Time, MnthlyToolTCnt.Type
FROM MnthlyToolTCnt


UNION ALL SELECT MnthlyWSSCnt.ProjectCriteria, MnthlyWSSCnt.CountOfForm_Record_Number, MnthlyWSSCnt.Type
FROM MnthlyWSSCnt;
```

And this is one of the query that pulls the data together for the Union Quer.

```
SELECT SSIReportsProjectCrit.ProjectCriteria, Count(MnthlyFireExData.Fire_Extinguisher_Location_ID_) AS CountOfFire_Extinguisher_Location_ID_, "Fire Extinguisher(s) Inspected" AS Type
FROM SSIReportsProjectCrit LEFT JOIN MnthlyFireExData ON SSIReportsProjectCrit.ProjectCriteria = MnthlyFireExData.Site_Location
GROUP BY SSIReportsProjectCrit.ProjectCriteria, "Fire Extinguisher(s) Inspected";
```

This query works no problem. It is pulling up the data.

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Presumably, something changed in one of the underlying tables.

Comment: The error says the types are wrong... you don't show us anything about the types of the tables you are working with -- what are the types of the tables you are working with?

Comment: Start by removing "Fire Extinguisher(s) Inspected" from Group By ..

Comment: @Hogan  "Typed incorrectly" in this error does not refer to the data types, rather the verb to "tap on keys on a keyboard" as in "input incorrectly".

Comment: @Gustav  Although the string literal in the Group By might look unnecessary, it is perfectly valid Access SQL and should cause no error.  Such an expression is automatically generated by the Query Designer for a literal value of an aggregate query.  The OP already stated that the individual queries and the union has worked in the past, so is there a particular reason for the suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Test that the unioned queries work individually.

- If they don't, something in the design of the tables may have changed. In any case, check that the queries are returning data of the same type.
- If they do, and you know that a) the whole union query has not changed at all and b) that it has worked in the past, then your intuition that the query is and has been fine is likely correct.

In my experience, I have found that this can also be due to corruption of the Access files. Sometimes, I would check for this first if I couldn't find any other logical explanation. In such cases, what has worked for me has been:

1. Attempt a Compact & Repair of the relevant file(s)
2. If the problem persists, then create a new Access file and import all objects from the old file to the new one, add any VBA references/libraries, compile it, Compact & Repair and then see if that fixes it.